# Identify 1980's Bianchi?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can someone please help me identify this bicycle?

My mom has had it in storage for ages – I believe it's from the 80's or early 90's. I'm not sure what is original and what was changed... But you all probably know far better than I, so here are some photos!

Thanks in advance :))

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

[image: vintage bianchi photo]

xx

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. This community has a fairly abysmal record of identifying bikes (because there are so many brands and models) but with the many clear pictures we probably have a decent chance of helping you out. Valuations are explicitly off-topic because they are only of use to the asker.

Comment: Mass-produced bikes are very unlikely to be valuable, even if they're 40 years old, so it won't much matter whether components are original or later replacements.

Comment: I tried to edit this to bring all the images in-line, but facebook only seems to allow linking for a short time.  Every URL is a broken link due to dates or signatures. Instead, the best way to get photos into this site is to use the little "Image" button above the editor.  The image gets uploaded to SE's part of Imgur and will be available longer than facebook's link.  Sorry, I can't fix this for you.

Answer (score 2):

The bike might be the a 1981 Rekord "W" Strada, at least this catalog page shows a very similar photo, but no exact parts list:
[image]
It might also be another Bianchi mixte-style frame with components swapped, i.e. flat bar to drop bar, which makes identification harder.

Or it might be a late '80s (possibly 1986) womens Bianchi Strada, as shown [in this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47829/is-this-a-real-vintage-bianchi-strada). Note that serial numbers on both bikes are very close: 51027534 vs 51027563.